# Getting error while compiling this PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

Package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EMP_DESIGNATION
AS
    PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS
    (
        design IN employee.designation%TYPE,
        incentive IN number
    );
    
END EMP_DESIGNATION;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EMP_DESIGNATION
AS
    PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS
    (
        design IN employee.designation%TYPE,
        incentive IN number
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        update Employee
        SET SALARY = SALARY + incentive
        where DESIGNATION = design;
        dbms_output.put_line(SQL%rowcount || ' employee record(s) are updated');
        
    END EMP_DETAILS;
END EMP_DESIGNATION;
/
```

Actually both this code is in same file I am getting bellow error message.

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PLS-00905: object P11169.EMP_DESIGNATION is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can some one please help me out in figuring out the error.

Comment: if all this sql is in the same file, you should have a "/" after the first END; (on a line by itself). And check if the first CREATE... is giving an error, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks buddy after adding "/" after first END the code compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL*Plus, run

```
show err
```

or - elsewhere - query `user_errors`; both will tell you what's invalid.

When I tried it (with a *dummy* `employee` table), everything seems to be fine:

```
SQL> create table employee(designation number, salary number);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EMP_DESIGNATION
  2  AS
  3      PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS
  4      (
  5          design IN employee.designation%TYPE,
  6          incentive IN number
  7      );
  8
  9  END EMP_DESIGNATION;
 10  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EMP_DESIGNATION
  2  AS
  3      PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS
  4      (
  5          design IN employee.designation%TYPE,
  6          incentive IN number
  7      )
  8      AS
  9      BEGIN
 10          update Employee
 11          SET SALARY = SALARY + incentive
 12          where DESIGNATION = design;
 13          dbms_output.put_line(SQL%rowcount || ' employee record(s) are updated');
 14
 15      END EMP_DETAILS;
 16  END EMP_DESIGNATION;
 17  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```